# Initiliazing a slice of structs of a third party library

Tags: go

I want to initialize a slice of structs (the structs are of type `&dns.ResourceRecordSet` ) where dns is the google cloud dns library. I am trying something like this

```
    rr := []*gcp.ResourceRecordSet {
    }{
        &gcp.ResourceRecordSet{
            Name:    "example.gcp.com",
            Ttl:     21600,
            Type:    "NS",
            Rrdatas: []string{"ns-cloud-c1.googledomains.com.", "ns-cloud-c2.googledomains.com.", "ns-cloud-c3.googledomains.com.", "ns-cloud-c4.googledomains.com."},
        },
        &gcp.ResourceRecordSet{
            Name:    "example.gcp.com",
            Ttl:     21600,
            Type:    "NS",
            Rrdatas: []string{"ns-cloud-c1.googledomains.com.", "ns-cloud-c2.googledomains.com.", "ns-cloud-c3.googledomains.com.", "ns-cloud-c4.googledomains.com."},
        },
    }
```

But I get an error saying `expected ';', found '{'` on the opening braces in the second line.

What is the correct syntax?

Comment: Delete the second line `}{`.

Comment: And you can leave out the `&` operator and the struct type when listing the elements–it's known from the literal type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra `}{` you shouldn't have, the code should look like this:

```
rr := []*gcp.ResourceRecordSet {
    &gcp.ResourceRecordSet{
        Name:    "example.gcp.com",
        Ttl:     21600,
        Type:    "NS",
        Rrdatas: []string{"ns-cloud-c1.googledomains.com.", "ns-cloud-c2.googledomains.com.", "ns-cloud-c3.googledomains.com.", "ns-cloud-c4.googledomains.com."},
    },
    &gcp.ResourceRecordSet{
        Name:    "example.gcp.com",
        Ttl:     21600,
        Type:    "NS",
        Rrdatas: []string{"ns-cloud-c1.googledomains.com.", "ns-cloud-c2.googledomains.com.", "ns-cloud-c3.googledomains.com.", "ns-cloud-c4.googledomains.com."},
    },
}
```

You're creating a slice literal with elements that are (addresses of) struct literals.  A slice literal looks like:

```
rr := []TYPE{
  element,
  element,
}
```

You instead had

```
rr := []TYPE{
}{
  element,
  element,
}
```